# finding a corrupted part from the parts of a split archive

Tags: rar

I have 7 files with extensions like xyz.rar.001 - xyz.rar.007 clearly they are parts of a single file. I have all the 7 parts. I join them using a file joiner into a single file xyz.rar and try to unrar them with WINRAR , it says that archive is corrupted                 It is clear that 1 or 2 parts are corrupted. IS THERE ANY WAY TO FIND THEM ?                  Please help I don't want to re download all of them                                              NOTE- winrar can detect a corrupt part if the parts were splitted using winrar (with extensions like part1.rar , part2.rar etc. ) but not if they are named as rar.001

Comment: It's entirely possible that they are not a single large file split into 7 parts, but a series of 7 rar files making up one multi-volume set. If that is the case, then you do not want to combine them, but rather use the right options to rar...

Comment: What kind of an answer are you expecting? Are you looking for a ready-made tool with the necessary functionality? Or are you prepared to write your own application that would use some library to process (test or unpack) the multi-volume archive until the broken part is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts .001 - .006 should have the same size. Check if there is a file with a different byte size.

Are there multiple files in the RAR or just the one? With multiple you could run a Test and see which is the first file to fail.

I think it's strange that there is a second tool used to split the RAR archive up. (e.g. [HJSplit](http://www.hjsplit.org/)) This lets me think that .002 could be a RAR archive too. Try opening xyz.rar.001 with WinRAR and test/exctract. It happens more that RAR archives have the extension .001 instead of .rar. [An example](http://www.srrdb.com/release/details/Sonic.Generations.MULTi6-PROPHET).

Naming your archives in WinRAR like this can be accomplished by putting "xyz.rar.001" as Archive name on the General tab and checking "Old style volume names" on the Advanced tab.

If I then join the files with HJSplit, I get one .rar file (that is corrupt). When I Test it, it says "Next volume is required". In the diagnostic messages I can see "The required volume is absent" and "CRC failed in X. The file is corrupt"

If there is one file stored inside the RAR and the RAR is indeed just chopped up into 7 pieces, there is no way of telling without additional files such as .sfv or .par2. (unless the RAR does not use compression: you can parse the underlying file for errors and calculate the part where it goes wrong)

Comment: Thanks for answer part 1 to 6 are of same byte size>when try to unrar.001 file winrar gives " unexpected end of archive which clearly means I must have to join all the parts first " > For rest of the parts (when extracted individually) it says " The archive is in either unknown format or damaged)> After using hjsplit to combine them in 1  archive and then using winrar it gives error " Unknown method in (null) "while 7-ZIP gives "unsupported compression method for the file xyz.rar">note that whole rar file contain 2 iso files . I am able to extract 2.iso file with winrar but can't get other one

Comment: If you can extract one iso file correctly, then the parts that correspond to that iso file will be fine. No way to tell which of the other parts are corrupt. (without having the extracted file already)

Comment: Does the file have a recovery record? You could try to repair the RAR file. Repair archive Alt+R in WinRAR.